# Custom QML element - Item or Component

Tags: qml

When declaring custom QML element in separate file (to be reusable across project(s)), which option is better, to declare it as `Item` or as `Component` and what are pros and cons for them?

Comment: I don't think that make sense. Are you talking about defining a component inline (using Component) versus defining a component using a separate file (wherein you're not limited to Item).

Comment: @JonasG.Drange using separate file, I've upgraded question.

Comment: Your qml file is already a Component. then you choose either Item or one of its descendats as your root element

Comment: `Component` is a prototype, a declaration of an object. `Item` is instance of this object. So you cannot create `Component` as is. In another way you can define your `Component` in 2 ways: in a separate file or wrap it in `Component`. But anyway, after you define it, you must create the object itself to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I had the same doubts and the following example helped me. I put it there, hoping it can help you.

Here is the component defined in a file somewhere:

```
// FooBar.qml
// import whatever.you.need
Rectangle { }
```

Here a possible use as involved as main item of another component definition:

```
// ...
Component {
    id: myFooBar
    FooBar { }
}
// ...
```

Well, what about if the first one was as it follows?

```
// FooBar.qml
// import whatever.you.need
Component {
    Rectangle { }
}
```

Actually it doesn't make much sense, besides the official documentation. Does it?

That's why I've never tried it... But I've also read the documentation, of course, as kindly pointed out by someone else!! It's far more helpful. :-)